# Printing text to webpage inside a Java method in JSP

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

I have been struggling to print text inside a Java method on a Java server page. Here are some ways I've attempted to print the text and errors thrown from the Tomcat (Version 7.0.56) compiler:

```
<%
class Base {
    public void main() {
    String Text = "ThisIsText";
    out.println(Text);
    }
}
%>
```

Error: Cannot refer to the non-final local variable out defined in an enclosing
scope

```
<%
class Base {
static Text;
public void main() {
String Text = "ThisIsText";
}
out.println(Text);
}
%>
```

Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName

```
<%
class Base {
static Text;
public String text() {
String Text = "NewText";
return Text;
}
}
%>
<%text();%>
```

The method text() is undefined for the type Base_jsp

Is there any way to print HTML Text directly from a Java method in a JSP scriptlet?

Comment: You do not (usually) define a class inside the JSP, the JSP will be compiled into one. Really, there are thousands and thousands of introductory tutorials to JSPs, please read some of them carefully instead of trying to learn from trial-and-askSO from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Use a declarative tag instead

```
 <%!

            class Base {

                JspWriter out;

                public Base(JspWriter out) {
                    this.out = out;
                }

                public void main() {
                    String Text = "ThisIsText";
                    try {
                        out.println(Text);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        %>
    <%(new Base(out)).main();%>
```

when you write something in `<%%>` the code between these tags is placed in methods so you cant declare function or class inside that tags because we cant have methods or class inside methods.

[**Similar**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226218/defining-a-class-in-a-jsp),[**Also check**](http://www.snippetit.com/2009/05/jsp-how-to-declare-methods-and-inner-class-in-jsp/)

Answer (score 0):

The `out` variable is already inside a method - `_jspService`. So if you are going to use `out`, declare another method that takes `out` as parameter using declaration - `<%!` and then just call this method.